# PHP class referencing confusion across multiple files

Tags: php, class, reference, new-operator, require

I have an index.php file that has 3 includes

```
<?php
require_once('mod.php');
$mod = new Mod();

require_once('start.php');
require_once('tools.php');

....some code....
?>
```

I need to be able to reference the $mod object inside the start.php and tools.php.
How do I pass that object to be referenced by those 2 other require files?

Basically the mod.php is a class that has an array list generated in its __construct(). I want to use that array list data inside the startup.php and tools.php file but not sure how to pass in the existing one without calling "new" inside both of those files separately which doesn't do what I need since it resets everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `require` (or `require_once`, `include`, or `include_once`), simply includes and evaluates the code.  The variable scope is inherited from the point at which the code is imported.

As an example, using your code:

```
<?php // index.php

require_once('mod.php');
$mod = new Mod();

require_once('start.php');
```

And the include:

```
<?php // start.php

$mod->arrayList(); // $mod is the object created in index.php
```

Comment: This will not work. For it to work, you need to say something like "global $mod" in start.php. BTW, this practices leads to completely unmaintainable code.

Comment: @Alex Why on earth would you need to do that? We're already in the global scope. And what about this is unmaintainable?

Comment: My apologies - you don't need a global statement here. You're correct, it does go into global scope with the setup you specified. It nevertheless is quite unmaintainable - $mod is a global variable defined in one file, and used in the other. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks lonesome.. it seems I just assumed it wouldn't pass. But Oli (Below) and Alex is right about using global $mod for functions within other classes. That also is working. As far as autoload, I am using it.. the demo code I used was simply for this question so I pulled it all apart.

Thanks all for your help! It's working great! Seems like "global and variable scope" is where I need to read up on. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using require() calls not for dynamic functionality loading (get a class definition in), but as something like a function call. Don't. Avoid global variables like a plague.

Side note: Instead of worrying about doing the require() calls in the right order to get your classes defined, I'd encourage you to look at Autoload functionality in PHP 5. It allows you to define which classes are defined in which file, and load those files on-demand when the classes are requested.

Comment: This did not answer a question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all use some autoloader. Dozens of `require` on the top of the file are annoying and needless.

You don't have to pass any references to other files. `require` works like "copy-paste-execute" so `$mod` will be available in that file.

```
#index.php
$mod = new Mod();
include 'file.php';

#file.php
$mod->doSth(); // works file!
```

Your problem is probably [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you need to use `$mod` inside another object (the fact that its source (class) is in another file doesn't matter) pass reference to `$mod` as a constructor argument, pass it using a special setter (`$obj->setMod($mod); $obj->doSth();`) or use more complex but better solution like Dependency Injection Container ([sample implementation](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/)).

Comment: +1 for explaining scope and how to preserve the instance of the first object.

Comment: Yes variable scope does sound like where my confusion lies. I'll read up on that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The mod should be available in those other files...if you need it in a function or class, use the global keyword, like:

```
    function test() {
        global $mod;

        print $mod->list;
    }
```

Comment: You can use a hammer to fix a microscope. It also works. Sometimes.

Comment: true, I should have suggested a singleton, at least that object won't re-initialize every time it's needed..But I'm curious how the autoload solution works out here

Comment: Well downvote or not.. this seems to work for me. I did need to reference the $mod object from within a function in another included class and global $mod; works. Is this not a good way?

Comment: @Oli: The purpose of Singleton is to provide one and only one instance of some class, not global access to it which is only a side effect.  Singleton used as a replacement for `global` becomes global itself and inherits all of its weakness. @DssTrainer: Here's explanation [why `global` is evil](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en-GB&q=why+global+is+evil&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (choose any, all should be good).

Comment: eh.. seems like a lot of fallout from the old vbasic 5 days where they were bad and the whole localized approach was the way to go. But global is there for a reason. Its like Select * is bad.. true.. but very useful in terms of dynamic expansion.. sometimes have to weigh the pros and cons.